# ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. pandas error in python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xpath

I am trying to create a dataframe by adding a condition to pick up only the uptill a certain attribute say "stack".

I have pandas 1.3.4 installed in my windows 10 and spyder IDE.

```
import pandas as pd

df_employee = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name')
df_cor = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email')
df_id = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id')
df_id2 = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='//id')
df_address = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id/address')
df_address2 = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='//address')
df_street = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id/address/street')
df_street2 = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='//street')
df_state = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id/address/street/state')
df_cell_cap = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id[@name="stack"]//address')
df_street_stack = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id[@name="stack"]//street')
```

The code works fine uptill this stage but when it hits the below line it throws error.

```
df_cell_cap = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id[@name="stack"]//address')
```

I have tried the below ways but the error is still there.

```
df_address_stack = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id[contains(@name,"stack")]//address')
df_address_stack = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath='employee_name/email/id/*[name() = 'stack']/address'
```

Error:

```
ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.
```

Is there anything that i am missing ?
Below is my sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee_name name="ndlkjfidm" date="dfhkryi">
    <email name="nnn" P="ffgnp" V="0.825" T="125c">
        <id name="stack">
            <address name="adas_jk3" type="entry">
                <street name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="!ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_LOW">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4619" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="4.63027e-10" jus="115.178" />
                    </temp>
                </street>
                <street name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_HIGH">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4644" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="1.52578e-14" jus="311.073" />
                    </temp>
                </street>
            </address>
        </id>
    </email>
</employee_name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample XML :

```
<employee_name name="ndlkjfidm" date="dfhkryi">
    <email name="nnn" P="ffgnp" V="0.825" T="125c">
        <id name="stack">
            <address name="adas_jk3" type="entry">
                <street name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="!ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_LOW">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4619" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="4.63027e-10" jus="115.178" />
                    </temp>
                </street>
                <street name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_HIGH">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4644" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="1.52578e-14" jus="311.073" />
                    </temp>
                </street>
            </address>
        </id>
    </email>
</employee_name>
```

If you go through the documentation for [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), you will find that xpath needs to be specified with a `//` prefix. You may or may not specify `.` period before slashes.

So your code should work fine with the following change

```
df_employee = pd.read_xml(filename,xpath='//employee_name')

        name     date  email
0  ndlkjfidm  dfhkryi    NaN

df_cor = pd.read_xml(filename,xpath='//employee_name/email')

  name      P      V     T  id
0  nnn  ffgnp  0.825  125c NaN

df_id = pd.read_xml(filename,xpath='//employee_name/email/id')

    name  address
0  stack      NaN

df_address_stack = pd.read_xml(filename,xpath='//employee_name/email/id[contains(@name,"stack")]//address')

   name   type  street
0  adas_jk3  entry     NaN
```

which gives us the expected output

Comment: Do not know for what reason but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Please post the exact xml you have becuase the one you posted is not in a proper xml format

Comment: Just one question. why street is getting printed as NaN instead of the values

Comment: Do you want to drop the street column

Comment: No. My question was there is Nan in every output instead of values. any reason ?

Comment: What we are trying to get here is only until the address tag and not tags within it

Comment: Can you suggest me on how to add. I want it to be added

Comment: You will have to get the street values in a spearate dataframe as street values are present as list inside the address tag

Comment: @PythonBang, try this `pd.read_xml(filename,xpath='//employee_name/email/id[contains(@name,"stack")]//address/street')`

Comment: upvoted and accepted as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df_id = pd.read_xml('employee.xml',xpath="//employee_name/email/id[contains(@name, 'stack')]")
```

Output:

```
    name    address
0   stack   NaN
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Why? I tested it with the provided file by @Himanshu Poddar. Please, first check it with his file, if it worked then the problem is with your data. Then, send us a correct version of your xml to work on it.